# Eloquent relation whereHas / with / sum

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get `all Projects where status is Not active and Vendor balance for that project is Not 0`.

The below gets me all Projects where status is Not active and (Vendor) Bid for that project is Not 0.
It seems I need to replace `where('amount' , '!=', 0)` with something else but I can't seem to figure it out as there is a lot of variables.

```
$balances = Project::whereHas('bids', function ($query) use ($vendor){
    $query->where('amount' , '!=', 0)->where('vendor_id', $vendor->id);
})->with(['bids' => function ($query) {
    $query->get()->where('latestStatus.title_id', '!=', 5);
}])->get();
```

To get the Vendor Balance for a projects I need to sum all Expenses for the vendor for each Project and subtract that from the Bid('amount'). Everything is on separate tables and I can elaborate as well.

Any any help is appreciated. Writing here and thinking through my issue really helps and everyone is really helpful.

Thanks! Patryk